# Just 4 Table Join query takes too much time and some time fail to execute

Tags: mysql, join, php, like

I am working on getting candidate detail from mysql database and for that i have created one query.

Is my query structure is wrong?

**Here is the query:**

```
SELECT  `candidate`.`id`, `candidate`.`email`, `candidate`.`fname`,
        `candidate`.`lname`, `candidate`.`id` as `can_id`, `candidate`.`update_date` AS `updated_at`,
        DATE_FORMAT(candidate.dob, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dob, `candidate`.`gender`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT candidate_experience.functional_area_name SEPARATOR ',') AS can_functional_area,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT candidate_experience.industry_type_name SEPARATOR ',') AS can_industry_type_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT qualification_name SEPARATOR ',') AS qualification_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT candidate_key_skills.name SEPARATOR ',') AS skill,
        `candidate_desired_job`.`current_location`,
        `candidate_desired_job`.`total_experiance`, `candidate_desired_job`.`prefered_location`,
`candidate_desired_job`.`notice_period`,
IFNULL(candidate_desired_job.expected_salary, 'N') AS expected_salary
    FROM  `candidate`
    LEFT JOIN  `candidate_key_skills`  ON `candidate_key_skills`.`candidate_id` = `candidate`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN  `candidate_qualification`  ON `candidate_qualification`.`candidate_id` = `candidate`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN  `candidate_desired_job`  ON `candidate_desired_job`.`candidate_id` = `candidate`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN  `candidate_experience`  ON `candidate_experience`.`candidate_id` = `candidate`.`id`
    WHERE  ( `name` LIKE '%PHP%' ESCAPE '!' )
      AND  ( `prefered_location` LIKE '%Ahmedabad%' ESCAPE '!' )
      AND  `total_experiance` >= '-1'
      AND  `total_experiance` <= '40'
      AND  `expected_salary` >= '0'
      AND  `expected_salary` <= '500000'
      AND  ( `candidate_experience`.`industry_type_name` LIKE '%Accommodation and  Food Services%' ESCAPE '!' 
           )
      OR  `carrier_summary` LIKE '%PHP%' ESCAPE '!'
      OR  `carrier_summary` LIKE '%Ahmedabad%' ESCAPE '!'
      OR  `carrier_summary` LIKE '%Accommodation
      and  Food Services%' ESCAPE '!'
      AND  `candidate`.`id` >0
    GROUP BY  `candidate_key_skills`.`candidate_id`, `candidate_desired_job`.`id`
    ORDER BY  `candidate_desired_job`.`id` DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Red flag!  `x AND y OR z` is the same as `(x AND y) OR z`.  I suspect you need parentheses around the `ORs`.

And something seems to be missing (even before my edit) on the last `OR`.

(I suggest you use short "aliases" to help de-clutter the query.)

Please qualify all columns.  Meanwhile, I will assume all the columns mentioned in the `WHERE` come from `candidate`, else some of the following will not be correct....

Leading wildcards with `LIKE` prevents usage of indexes, so I will ignore `name`, etc.  Can you use `FULLTEXT` instead of `LIKE`?

ids are usually positive values, so why do you have `AND  candidate.id >0`??

So, we are down to two choices for a useful `INDEX`: `(total_experiance)` or `(expected_salary)`.  But I suspect neither of those will be very useful.

As for the 4 `LEFT JOINs` -- Are they "many:1"

Ouch.  2 different tables in the `GROUP BY`.  That forces the generation of a temp table leading into the `GROUP BY`.  That temp table will have lots of rows, and be slow.

Since the `ORDER BY` is different than the `GROUP BY`, there will be another temp table and sort.  This can be avoided by saying

```
ORDER BY `candidate_key_skills`.`candidate_id` DESC,
         `candidate_desired_job`.`id` DESC
```

to match the `GROUP BY`.  This will speed up the query a little.

Ordinarily I would suggest a subquery instead of a `LEFT JOIN`, thereby avoiding some of the "inflation" caused by the join.  But I see that each case involves two select items.

Sorry, there is not much that will speed up the query.